# OpenGL Link Error for GLFW DDS Load function

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, linker, glfw

I have been working my way through the OpenGL-tutorial.org tutorial series. All has been working fine, however I have not been able to get Tutorial 5 to work in my playground executable, though it does work when run from the example tutorial 5 executable. This is true even when I copy and paste the example code over.

I receive the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:



"loadDDS(char const*)", referenced from:

_main in playground.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below is the link log:

```
Ld playground/playground normal x86_64
cd /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/ogl-master
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/ogl-master/playground -F/Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/ogl-master/playground -filelist /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/OpenGL/Tutorials.build/Debug/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/OpenGL/Tutorials.build/Debug/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -framework OpenGL -framework OpenGL /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/OpenGL/external/glfw-3.1.2/src/Debug/libglfw3.a /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/OpenGL/external/Debug/libGLEW_1130.a -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreVideo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/OpenGL/Tutorials.build/Debug/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/RufusVijayaratnam/rufus/Coding/ogl-master/playground/playground
```

So the error appears to be that when the function `loadDDS()` is called that it is not found. I am unsure as to why this is. The function is declared in `texture.ccp` which is in a folder (called 'common'), along with `texture.hpp`. `texture.hpp` has the code below:

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_HPP
#define TEXTURE_HPP
// Load a .DDS file using GLFW's own loader
GLuint loadDDS(const char * imagepath);

#endif
```

In `playground.cpp` there is:

`include<texture.hpp>`

Why can't `loadDDS()` be found, even though I have set the working directory of the playground function to the same as that for Tutorial 5, and the code in `playground.ccp` and 'tutorial05.ccp' is exactly the same?

Comment: "From trying to find a solution, it appears that what could have caused the issue is the GLFW library was not linked." How did you reach at such a conclusion? `GLuint loadDDS(const char * imagepath)` is a function provided by the tutorial itself.

Comment: @derhass Yes that is true, I was unable to find a solution for this situation, however it was the “undefined symbols for architecture” part that I was able to find people with similar issues, with a common suggestion solution being a library not being linked.

Comment: The error message clearly states that your `main` function calls a function named `loadDDS` which can't be found. And that function simply isn't part of any library, it is provided as source code in the tutorial and supposed to be copied into your code.

Comment: @derhass Oh, thank you. I wasn’t aware that was what the error meant. Though in the code it includes the exact same headers as found in tutorial 5, and I have set the working directory correctly, so I’m not sure how it cannot find the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for the playground executable (doesn't work)
>
> ```
> # User playground add_executable(playground 
>     playground/playground.cpp
>     common/shader.cpp
>     common/shader.hpp )
> ```
>
> and finally for tutorial 5 (does work)
>
> ```
> # Tutorial 5
> add_executable(tutorial05_textured_cube
>     tutorial05_textured_cube/tutorial05.cpp
>     common/shader.cpp
>     common/shader.hpp
>     common/texture.cpp
>     common/texture.hpp
> ```

So I'm making the educated guess that `loadDDS()` is implemented in `texture.cpp`, and since you did not add this file, it won't be compiled, and the resulting object file won't be linked, and the symbol will just not be found.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right. Updating the CMakeLists.txt to include common/texture.cpp and common/texture.hpp in the playground executable generation fixed the issue.